# html.ActionLink links not returning expected value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have the following ActionLink

```
Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", New With {.class = "tab"})
```

But it creates the following Link in the address bar http://localhost:1028/?Length=4 as opposed to what I expect it to be as http://localhost:1028/Home.

Have I done something wrong to cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload of ActionLink. Try:

```
Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", Nothing, New With {.class = "tab"})
```

...hoping I've got my VB syntax right...